# Pandas Series value_counts working differently for different counts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(np.arange(1,7),3), columns=['A'])

df1.A.value_counts(sort=False)
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(np.arange(1,7),100), columns=['A'])

df2.A.value_counts(sort=False)
1    100
2    100
3    100
4    100
5    100
6    100
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

---

In the above examples the `value_counts` works perfectly and give the required result. whereas when coming to larger dataframes it is giving a different output. Here the `A` values are already sorted and counts are also same, but the order of index that is `A` changed after `value_counts`. Why is it doing correctly for small counts but not for large counts:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(np.arange(1,7),1000), columns=['A'])

df3.A.value_counts(sort=False)
4    1000
1    1000
5    1000
2    1000
6    1000
3    1000
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Here I can do `df3.A.value_counts(sort=False).sort_index()` or `df3.A.value_counts(sort=False).reindex(df.A.unique())`. I want to know the reason why it is behaving differently for different counts?

Using:

```
Numpy version :1.15.2
Pandas version :0.23.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a *known* problem.

If you browse through the source code -

1. `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithims.py` line `581` is the original implementation
2. It calls `_value_counts_arraylike` for `int64` values when `bins=None`
3. This function makes a call - `keys, counts = htable.value_count_int64(values, dropna)`

If you then look at the `htable` implementation you will conclude that the keys are in an arbitrary order, subject to how the `hashtable` works.

Its not a guarantee of ANY kind of ordering. Typically this routine sorts by biggest values, and that is almost always what you want.

I guess they can change this to have `sort=False` mean original ordering. I don't know if this would actually break anything (and done internally this isn't very costly as the uniques are already known).

The order is *changed* from [`pandas/hashtable.pyx.build_count_table_object()`](https://github.com/dieterv77/pandas-1/blob/master/pandas/hashtable.pyx). Resizing of the `pymap` moves the entries by hashing values.

Here is the [full](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12679) discussion

Comment: When keys are in an arbitrary order, it must not guarantee for any number of counts right? but if the counts are small it is preserving the order and if the counts are high it isn't. Also, it maintains order till 341 counts but fails after it.

Comment: It looks to be some update for orignal order retaining [github page](https://github.com/tomspur/pandas/commit/92f8dbc5c3e8dfe8d4b0c456278abf4562ba4fa8) look to be using same update as `reindex(unique(values))` :-)  that's only way, So one have to reindex  to preseve the orignal ordering